# Executing command instead of setting as variable in bash

Tags: bash, variables

I am simply trying to gather information about the system, specifically the hostname, OS, and SSH version.  I created the following script and it sets the hostname and OS but instead of setting the SSH command as variable, it executes it and I can't figure out why.

Here is the script

```
#! /bin/bash

set -o xtrace
rm -f ssh.log 
HOSTNAME=$(hostname)
OS=$(uname -s)
SSH_VER=$(ssh -V)

echo $HOSTNAME $OS $SSH_VER > ssh.log

cat ssh.log
```

Here is the output of script...

```
+ rm -f ssh.log
++ hostname
+ HOSTNAME=localhost.localdomain
++ uname -s
+ OS=Linux
++ ssh -V OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.0-fips 29 Mar 2010
+ SSH_VER=
+ echo localhost.localdomain Linux
+ cat ssh.log localhost.localdomain Linux
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ssh -V` does print its output to `stderr` not to `stdout`. To get the desired output you need to change

```
SSH_VER=$(ssh -V)
```

to

```
SSH_VER=$(ssh -V 2>&1)
```

this will redirect to output of `stderr` to `stdout`.

Visit http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html for more information on bash redirections.

Comment: That was it!! The nuance of shell scripting is maddening to say the least

Answer (score 1):

ssh -v outputs on stderr (>&2), not stdout (>&1).
try:

```
 SSH_VER="$(ssh -V 2>&1)"
 echo "$HOSTNAME $OS $SSH_VER" > ssh.log #in case it's multiline
```

Comment: use ">>" if you just want to append to ssh.log, and not truncate+overwrite it